# Linking 3 types of document for a view

Tags: view, couchdb

I'm struggling with linked documents when creating a view.

> A salesperson has multiple clients, each client has multiple
>   purchases.

I need to get a view containing:

salesperson ids for each client purchase.

In a relational database I would join:

```
purchase.clientid -> client._id
                     client.salesperson -> salesperson._id
```

Given:

```
{ _id: "1", type: "purchase", clientid: "2", items: [] }
{ _id: "2", type: "client", salespersonid: "3", name: "Chris the client" }
{ _id: "3", type: "salesperson", name: "Simon the salesperson" }
```

I've tried reading a lot of stuff, but nothing has clicked. How would I do this in a view?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   _id: 'purchase-client-2-<unique-purchase-id>',
   salespersonId: 'sales-3'
}

{
   _id: 'sales-3',
   name: 'Simon the salesperson'
}

{
   _id: 'client-2',
   name: 'Chris the client'
}
```

With the above documents you could query for all documents starting with 'purchase-client2' to get an array of purchase document. Each purchase document then tells you who the sales person was.  Depending on the number of sales staff you may already have everything you need right there, assuming your map of sales id to name is already in memory.

If not, you could do a further lookup (and potentially cache that result). If that in-memory lookup or extra lookup doesn't work for you you could also duplicating the sales person's name in the purchase document.  After all, NoSQL DB's don't follow the same rules as relational DB's and it's ok to duplicate now and again.  You just have to think about how you keep the dups sync'ed up later.

If you can use and abuse the ID field and getaway without views then you may be better off.  Views bring their own set of problems.  Good luck!